# Filter by least value in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can we able to filter by least value in net-suite, I tried `CASE WHEN MIN({custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld})<>{custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` Its not Working.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this sort of thing is really difficult in Netsuite. It would be fairly simple to do with a script though so if this answer doesn't work you might get better results describing the context of what you are trying to do.

In SQL we'd be able to use a subquery or at worst a correlated subquery to generate the minimum to test against.

You can't do that in Netsuite.

If your field custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld is numeric then what you can do is move your formula numeric field to the result so that the minimum valued groups are not included like:

```
CASE WHEN MIN({custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld})<>{custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld} THEN {custrecord_carr_cus_base_fld}  ELSE 0 END
```